# C# MySQL Raspberry Pi - Access denied for user

Tags: c#, mysql, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2

Heyhey!

I am having issues with my MySQL server on my Raspberry pi.
It works flawlessly to connect remotely from both my PC and from others in my house, but when I send the application to my friend, they get:

"Access denied for user "Admin2"----."

Things I've tried:

• Quoting out the bind-address in my config file, as well as using my static IP from my RPI, and also using 0.0.0.0 as IP.

• Added the line "skip-name-resolve" in my "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" file.

• Port 3306 is open on my router. Checked it using CanYouSeeMe.

The following queries:

```
CREATE USER 'Admin2'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database.* TO 'Admin2'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

SHOW GRANTS FOR 'Admin2';
|
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'Admin2'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '<Lots of encrypted password letters here I assume>'
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON 'database.* TO 'Admin2'@'%'
```

I have a loginData.settings in my Visual Studio project with the strings: username, password & ipString which each has a textbox assigned to them that saves the info. We tried connecting using my Pi's static IP as well as the IP obtained from whatsmyip.

```
project.loginData.Default.username = this.usernameText.Text;
project.loginData.Default.password = this.passwordText.Text;
project.loginData.Default.ipString = this.ipTest.Text;
```

And finally the connect string.

```
string wsUN = project.loginData.Default.username;
string wsPW = project.loginData.Default.password;
string wsIP = project.loginData.Default.ipString;

string projectConnect = "datasource=" + wsIP + ";port=3306;username=" + wsUN + ";password=" + wsPW;
```

I am completely clueless. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget that MySQL is set to only listen on 127.0.0.1 by default. In other words the default instance does not listen to public IP Addresses. Bind it instead to 0.0.0.0 otherwise it will listen only local linux sockets.

Comment: Changed, saved and restarted mysql. Still same issue, buddy.

Comment: Do you have port 3306 forwarded on your router?

Comment: Yes sir. Both TCP and UDP opened

Comment: Try just in case the inline `GRANT/CREATE` syntax. I.E. `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database.* TO 'admin2'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';`  Maybe your grant is giving a blank password to your user for that specific table?  I think that depends on the version of mysql.

Comment: Still same issue. I checked the grants for the user    SHOW GRANTS FOR Admin2. Updated the main post with the info I got.

Comment: I had not forwarded the port using the IP on my PI. Works flawlessly now.
Super happy! Thanks!